# combining lag with row computation in windowing apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

assume there is a dataframe as follows:

```
 a| b| 
 1| 3| 
 1| 5| 
 2| 6|  
 2| 9| 
 2|14|
```

I want to produce a final dataframe like this

```
 a| b|  c
 1| 3|  0
 1| 5| -2
 2| 6| -6
 2| 9| -10
 2| 14| -17
```

The value of c is computed for every row except the first one as a-b+c for the previous row. I tried to use lag as well as rowsBetween, but no success Since "c" value does not exist and it is filled with random variable!!

```
val w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy($"a", $"b)
df.withColumn("c", lead($"a", 1, 0).over(w) - lead($"b", 1, 0).over(w) + lead($"c", 1, 0).over(w))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't reference `c` while calculating `c`; What you need is a cumulative `sum`, which could simply be:

```
df.withColumn("c", sum(lag($"a" - $"b", 1, 0).over(w)).over(w)).show

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  3|  0|
|  1|  5| -2|
|  2|  6| -6|
|  2|  9|-10|
|  2| 14|-17|
+---+---+---+
```

But note this is inefficient due to the lack of the partition column.

Comment: Thanks. That's very cool. Can I extend it? For example, can I reset the "c" value to 0 if it is greater than a threshold (let's say -7)?

Comment: That's not an easy task at least if you stick to data frame API. You might want do this at the RDD level.

Comment: @justin yes that can be easy by writing another withColumn and reseting the value in c column. And as Psidom has pointed out that it would be very difficult to do it in one withColumn

Comment: any solution with more than one withcolumn operations for dataframes?